# Observium - Graphs shows no data (nan) or empty graphs

Tags: system-administration, observium

I have problem with Observium. 
On CentOS 7 I installed Observium. On this server i also have DirectAdmin and Wordpress.
When I login to webpanel Observium, Graphs shows no data (nan).
[Graphs no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZkAd.jpg)

```
<?php

## Check http://www.observium.org/docs/config_options/ for documentation of possible settings

## It's recommended that settings are edited in the web interface at /settings/ on your observium installation.
## Authentication and Database settings must be hardcoded here because they need to work before you can reach the web-based configuration interface

// Database config ---  This MUST be configured
$config['db_extension'] = 'mysqli';
$config['db_host']      = 'localhost';
$config['db_user']      = 'root';
$config['db_pass']      = '[MyPassword]';
$config['db_name']      = 'observium';

$config['ping'] = "/usr/sbin/ping";
$config['fping'] = "/usr/sbin/fping";

// Base directory
#$config['install_dir'] = "/opt/observium";

// Default community list to use when adding/discovering
$config['snmp']['community'] = array("public");

// Authentication Model
$config['auth_mechanism'] = "mysql";    // default, other options: ldap, http-auth, please see documentation for config help

// Enable alerter
// $config['poller-wrapper']['alerter'] = TRUE;

//$config['web_show_disabled'] = FALSE;    // Show or not disabled devices on major pages.

// Set up a default alerter (email to a single address)
//$config['email']['default']        = "user@your-domain";
//$config['email']['from']           = "Observium <observium@your-domain>";
//$config['email']['default_only']   = TRUE;

$config['enable_syslog']                = 1; // Enable Syslog

// End config.php
```

I do not see any error when I manually execute:

```
cd /opt/observium && ./discovery.php -h all && ./poller.php -h all
```

My /etc/cron.d/observium  file

```
33 */6 * * *   root    cd /opt/observium/ && ./discovery.php -h all >> /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * *   root    cd /opt/observium/ && ./discovery.php -h new >> /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * *   root    cd /opt/observium/ && ./poller.php -h all >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

you used incorrect polling time (15 mins). Correct polling time is 5min. Use cron entries as described in official install guide [CentOS Cron](https://docs.observium.org/install_rhel7/#cron):

```
# Run a complete discovery of all devices once every 6 hours
33  */6   * * *   root    /opt/observium/discovery.php -h all >> /dev/null 2>&1

# Run automated discovery of newly added devices every 5 minutes
*/5 *     * * *   root    /opt/observium/discovery.php -h new >> /dev/null 2>&1

# Run multithreaded poller wrapper every 5 minutes
*/5 *     * * *   root    /opt/observium/poller-wrapper.py >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem with installation as it was in my case. Observium has bug here [Observium bugreport](https://jira.observium.org/browse/OBS-2551) with explonation "install it again exactly according to the manual". Good page to use for installation information is this [observium installation guide](https://docs.observium.org/install_debian/).

Problem in my case was that I had a observium folder with all scripts in Documents folder and symlink for `html` subfolder to `/opt/observium/html`. I fixed that by making symling of whole `observium` folder to `/opt/observium/` which is set according to observium manual `DocumentRoot` in
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/observium/html
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /opt/observium/html/>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```